# How can we substitute for the bottom term in a differential?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say we have an expression for $\frac{dx}{dt}=5x$, but we want to substitute $t'=5t$ to get $\frac{dx}{dt'}$. How would we do this?

My intuition was that $\frac{dx}{dt'}=5\frac{dx}{dt}$ for the following reason. Previously, we were asking how much $x$ is changing for an infinitesimal change in $t$, but now we are asking how much $x$ is changing for a 5-times larger change, so the derivative should be 5-times as large.

However, the book I'm working from seems to indicates that $\frac{dx}{dt'}=1/5\frac{dx}{dt}$, but doesn't provide reasoning. How do we go about performing this substitution?

Comment: what does the chain rule tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard formula is:$$\frac{dx}{dt'}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{dt'}$$
Since $t=t'/5$,$\frac{dt}{dt'}=1/5$.

The intuition is that when you change $t'$ by a bit, $t$ is get changed by $1/5$ as much, so $x$ changes by $1/5$ as much.